# How to convert "RIFF WAVEfmt..." to audio, any language can do that?

Tags: javascript, php

i use jquery ajax call api and get 1 result string "RIFF WAVEfmt..." with format as "audio/wav", i don't know how to convert it to audio and play. Can anyone help me?

Comment: _"i don't know how to convert it to audio and play"_ - **it already is** a playable audio file - pass the `Blob` object into a `HTMLAudioElement` to play it.

Comment: can you give me an example?